# Is there a way to build multiple apps from single one with replacing some assets and components?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I have a folder structure of my create-react-app project below. I have a single project but multiple results. While I am developing and building **projectA**, I want to copy all the files under the **projectA** folder and paste them where necessary.

I can use theming but there are a lot of projects to build and the component can change totally related to project. In this method, **login.js** and some other components will have separate condition blocks for every projects. These components will be very messy after a few projects. And I don't want the logo of other projects in the build file.

I choose overriding necessary files dynamically. I am looking for a best practice. Please help.

```
projectA
    public
        index.html
        favicon.ico
    src 
        images
            logo.png
        pages
            page.js (this extends base_page)

projectB
    public
        index.html
        favicon.ico
    src 
        images
            logo.png
        pages
            page.js (this extends base_page)

public
    index.html
    favicon.ico
src
    images
        logo.png
    pages
        app.js
        base_page.js
        page.js (this extends base_page)
    index.js
```

Comment: letting the person answering know if he/she helped you is considered good habit :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but I think you first have to restructure your folders:

```
project
 |--webpack.config.js
 `--src
     |--common
     |   `--pages
     |      |--base-page.js
     |      `--other-resources.js
     |--appA
     |   |--images
     |   |  `--logoA.png
     |   `--pages
     |      `--page.js
     |--appB
     |   |--images
     |   |  `--logoB.png
     |   `--pages
     |      `--page.js
     ...
```

Then in your `appA/pages/page.js`, you can do something like

```
import Page from '../../common/pages/base-page'
```

And in your webpack, the entry can be

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/appA/index.js',
    './src/appB/index.js',
    // other apps
  ]
}
```

However I'm not sure if this is possible without ejecting create-react-app.